# Add passwords to config.yml to manage multiple sites

Tags: wp-cli

Is there a way to add a password for each site in my `config.yml` file so that I can manage multiple sites with different usernames and passwords?

It looks like I can add the username, but it prompts me for the password for each site as it connects.  It would be great if I could add them to the config file so that it runs automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SSH to connect to your sites then you can set up [SSH aliases in your SSH config file](http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/). There are many advantages to doing this, one of them being that you use your SSH key to login to sites rather than having to type passwords. I do this with WP-CLI and it has been a huge convenience for me.